# Batch file error because of space in input string

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm trying to make a table of possible inputs for the end user, but one of the inputs is causing the program to crash as there is a space. I know that usually enclosing the input with " " is the correct thing to do, but it does not work in this case, here is the code:

```
SET /P ANSWER=%ANSWER%
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={help} (goto :FunctionList)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={?} (goto :FunctionList)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={clear} (goto :clear)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :yes)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={tutorial} (goto :tutorial)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={New User} (goto :NewUser) **--Offending line**
```

The line :

```
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={New User} (goto :NewUser)
```

refuses to go to the the following part, regardless of the `{New User}` being inclosed by " " or not.

```
:NewUser
    SET /P USERNAME=Please enter your desired username:
    SET /P PASSWORD=Please enter your desired password:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I know that usually enclosing the input with " " is the correct thing to do

> but it does not work in this case

```
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={help} (goto :FunctionList)
```

When `%ANSWER%` is `New User` it contains a `Space` and is treated as two separate strings by the `if` command.

---

#### Solution

Enclose the `if` expressions in `"`s:

```
if /i "%ANSWER%"=="help" (goto :FunctionList)
if /i "%ANSWER%"=="?" (goto :FunctionList)
if /i "%ANSWER%"=="clear" (goto :clear)
if /i "%ANSWER%"=="yes" (goto :yes)
if /i "%ANSWER%"=="tutorial" (goto :tutorial)
if /i "%ANSWER%"=="New User" (goto :NewUser)
```

---

#### Delimiters

If the string being compared by an `IF` command includes delimiters such as `Space` or `Comma`, then either the delimiters must be escaped with a caret `^` or the whole string must be "quoted".

> This is so that the `IF` statement will treat the string as a single item and not as several separate strings.

Source [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.

Answer (score 0):

I had a batch script where I was checking whether a parameter inputted was blank.

```
IF "%3"=="" (SET "NumberToStartWith=1")
```

When the input was something like `" after"`, with spaces before the word, I would get an error like the following:

```
after""=="" was unexpected at this time.
```

Changing my code by adding a `~` character to remove any quotes from the input fixed the error:

```
IF "%~3"=="" (SET "NumberToStartWith=1")
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964238/3171509) for more information about what the `~` character does, and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check and refuse blanl or space in input I use the trick to change space to - and the check ...

```
@echo off
echo Check if input = blank or space
:MYSTART
REM cls
set input=-
set /p  input= Your input: 
set input=%input%-
REM replace space with -
set input=%input: =-%
REM  check if space
IF [%input%] EQU [--] cls & echo ********* input not OK & GOTO MYSTART
REM  check if blank (enter)
IF [%input%] EQU [-]  GOTO MYSTART
ECHO go haed ...
```

Comment: Do you mean "blank"? Also, note that this is an old question with a very thorough accepted answer already. Adding answers to these sorts of posts should only be done if you have a significantly different answer to provide with very new information.